# Modificar Archivo resgistros c++

Tags: c++, archivo, dev-c++

Hola he estado intentando modificar archivos de C++. Lo que quería es: si meto el nombre y el apellido de la persona lo busque y si lo encuentra le pida modificar el peso y altura para sacar su nuevo IMC pero nunca me encuentra nada, ¿alguna sugerencia?.

```
case 2:
        Leer.open("Base.txt");
        Leer>>nom;
        bool encontrado=false;
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la persona que desea modificar"<<endl;
        cin>>bnom;
        cout<<"Ingrese el apellido de la persona que desea modificar"<<endl;
        cin>>bapell;            
        while(!Leer.eof()){
            Leer>>nom;
            if(nom == bnom){
                encontrado=true;
                cout<<"Nombre"<<nom<<endl;
                cout<<"Apellido"<<apell<<endl;
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"Ingrese su nueva altura"<<endl;
                cin>>nal;
                cout<<"Ingrese su nuevo peso"<<endl;
                cin>>npes;
                IMCAct= npes / (nal*nal);
                Temp<<nom<<" "<<apell<<" "<<nal<<" "<<" "<<npes<<IMCAct;
                
            }
            else{
                    Temp<<nom<<" "<<apell<<" "<<al<<" "<<" "<<pes<<IMCinc;
            }
            Leer>>nom;
        }
        if(encontrado==false){
            cout<<"Usuario no encontrado no encontrada"<<endl;
        }
        Leer.close();
        Temp.close();
        remove("Base.txt");
        rename("Temp.txt","Base.txt");
        break;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipos de datos son `nom`, `bnom` y `bapell`?

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Usualmente para este tipo de problemas tenemos que probar el código en nuestras maquinas, usar un debugger, hacer cambios, etc. Para que se nos haga mas fácil ayudarte, procura publicar suficiente código, y otros archivos relevantes, para que nosotros podamos copiar, pegar, y reproducir el problema que tu tienes. De esa forma recibirás una respuesta mas rápida.

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que uses funciones por cada case, así en dado caso te da un error sabes en estará. Yo hice un código el cual tengo la función de buscar.
Te lo comparto para que puedas guiarte.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>


using namespace std;

HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
 
 
//variables a utilizar
typedef struct {
    int codigo, edad, telefono;
    char nombre[50], grados[100], estado[20];
    

} tprofesores;




void continuar()
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 3);
    printf("\n\n\n*****Presione una tecla para continuar*****\n\n");
    getch();
    system("cls");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7);
}




//crea el archivo
void crear()
{
    FILE* arch;
    arch = fopen("profesores.txt", "wb");
    if (arch == NULL)
        exit(1);
    fclose(arch);
    continuar();
}



//registra los datos
void cargar()
{
    FILE* arch;
    arch = fopen("profesores.txt", "ab");
    if (arch == NULL)
        exit(1);
    tprofesores profesores;
    
    printf("\nIngrese el codigo del profesor:");
    scanf("%i", &profesores.codigo);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\nIngrese el nombre y apellido completo del profesor:");
    gets(profesores.nombre);
    
    printf("\nIngrese el estado civil del profesor:");
    gets(profesores.estado);
    
    printf("\nIngrese los grados que imparte el profesor:");
    gets(profesores.grados);
    
    printf("\nIngrese el numero de telefono del profesor:");
    scanf("%i", &profesores.telefono);
    
    printf("\nIngrese edad del profesor:");
    scanf("%i", &profesores.edad);
    
    
    fwrite(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
    fclose(arch);
    continuar();
}



//muestra un listado de los registro
void listado()
{
    FILE* arch;
    arch = fopen("profesores.txt", "rb");
    if (arch == NULL)
        exit(1);
    tprofesores profesores;
    fread(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
    
     SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);
    
        printf("\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________");
        printf("\n|codigo\t\tnombre y apellido\tedad\testado civil\ttelefono\tgrados que imparte   |");
        printf("\n|____________________________________________________________________________________________________|");
        
    while (!feof(arch))
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 6);
        printf("\n|%i\t\t%s\t\t%i\t%s\t\t%i\t%s|\n", profesores.codigo, profesores.nombre, profesores.edad, profesores.estado, profesores.telefono, profesores.grados);
        fread(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
    }
    fclose(arch);
    continuar();
}



//busqueda de registro
void consulta()
{
    FILE* arch;
    arch = fopen("profesores.txt", "rb");
    if (arch == NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("\nIngrese el codigo del profesor a buscar:");
    int cod;
    scanf("%i", &cod);
    tprofesores profesores;
    int existe = 0;
    fread(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
   
   
   
    while (!feof(arch))
    {
        if (cod == profesores.codigo)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);
            printf("\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________");
            printf("\n|codigo\t\tnombre y apellido\tedad\testado civil\ttelefono\tgrados que imparte   |");
            printf("\n|____________________________________________________________________________________________________|");
            
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 6);
            printf("\n|%i\t\t%s\t\t%i\t%s\t\t%i\t%s|", profesores.codigo, profesores.nombre, profesores.edad, profesores.estado, profesores.telefono, profesores.grados);
            existe = 1;
            break;
        }
        fread(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
    }//cierra while
    
    
    if (existe == 0)
    printf("\n\n***No existe un profesor con dicho codigo***\n");
    fclose(arch);
    continuar();
}



//modificar datos del profesor
void modificacion()
{
    FILE* arch;
    arch = fopen("profesores.txt", "r+b");
    if (arch == NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("\nIngrese el codigo del profesor a modificar:");
    int cod;
    scanf("%i", &cod);
    tprofesores profesores;
    int existe = 0;
    fread(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
    
    while (!feof(arch))
    {
        if (cod == profesores.codigo)
        {
            
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);
   
            printf("\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________");
            printf("\n|codigo\t\tnombre y apellido\tedad\testado civil\ttelefono\tgrados que imparte   |");
            printf("\n|____________________________________________________________________________________________________|");
        
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 6);
            printf("\n|%i\t\t%s\t\t%i\t%s\t\t%i\t%s|\n", profesores.codigo, profesores.nombre, profesores.edad, profesores.estado, profesores.telefono, profesores.grados);
            
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7);
            printf("\n\nIngrese nueva edad:");
            scanf("%i", &profesores.edad);
            
            
            printf("\n\nIngrese estado civil del profesor:");
            scanf("%s", &profesores.estado);
            
        
            printf("\n\nIngrese nuevo numero de telefono del profesor:");
            scanf("%i", &profesores.telefono);
            
            
            printf("\n\nIngrese nuevo grado a impartir:");
            scanf("%s", &profesores.grados);
            
            
            int pos = ftell(arch) - sizeof(tprofesores);
            fseek(arch, pos, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
            
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 5);
   
            printf("\n\n***Se modificaron los datos del profesor.***\n");
            existe = 1;
            break;
        }
        fread(&profesores, sizeof(tprofesores), 1, arch);
    }//cierra while
    
    
    if (existe == 0)
       
        printf("\n\n***No existe un profesor con dicho codigo***\n");
    fclose(arch);
    continuar();
}




int main()
{

//color(hconsole, 7);
 
    int opcion;
    do {
        printf("1 - (seleccionar si no se ha creado)   Crear un archivo binario llamado \"profesores.txt\"\n");
        printf("2 - Registrar datos de profesores\n");
        printf("3 - Listado completo de los profesores.\n");
        printf("4 - Busqueda de un profesor.\n");
        printf("5 - Modificacion de datos de un profesor. \n");
        printf("6 - Finalizar\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese su opcion:");
        scanf("%i", &opcion);
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:crear();
            break;
        case 2:cargar();
            break;
        case 3:listado();
            break;
        case 4:consulta();
            break;
        case 5:modificacion();
            break;
        }

    } while (opcion != 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Abraham Mendoza Gracias fue de mucha ayuda